# linux record audio (arecord or similair) and seperate left/right channel

Tags: linux, audio, alsa, recording

I want to record (line in) from an audio device and seperate the left and right channel each to a different process. or record them seperately of course.
what I want is something like that (play command just as example):
either:

```
arecord (left channel only) -q -D plughw:1,0 -f S16_LE -r 22050 | play -t raw -r 22050 -b 16 -e signed -q - 
arecord (right channel only) -q -D plughw:1,0 -f S16_LE -r 22050 | play -t raw -r 22050 -b 16 -e signed -q -
```

(may also result in device or resource busy?)
or something like

`"arecord | splitchannels (leftchannel | process 1) (rightchannel | process 2)"`

or possibly more like that

`"arecord | tee >(getleftchannel | process1) >(getrightchannel | process2) > /dev/null"`

as intensive web searches didn't give any usable results..

any idea how I can accomplish that?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

after more web search and try and fail I found a solution:
"sox remix" works:
so the command I use looks like that (play just as example destination again)

```
arecord -q -D plughw:1,0 -f S16_LE -r 22050 -c2 | tee >(sox -t raw -r 22050 -b 16 -e signed -c 2 - -t raw -r 22050 -b 16 -e signed -c 1 - remix 1 | play -t raw -r 22050 -b 16 -e signed -q -) >(sox -t raw -r 22050 -b 16 -e signed -c 2 - -t raw -r 22050 -b 16 -e signed -c 1 - remix 2 | play -t raw -r 22050 -b 16 -e signed -q -) >/dev/null
```

remix 1 gives left and remix 2 right channel